# gcc how to suppress incompatible pointer type warning?

Tags: gcc, warnings, compiler-warnings

In our project warnings are treated as Error. This rule is applied from top level makefile.

I want to suppress warnings for the third party code.

I am getting "incompatible pointer type" warning when passing arguments to a function call.

I tried "-Wno-incompatible-pointer-types". But, its not supported by the compiler.

I'm using gcc.c4.2.1-p4.ppc-linux.

Can someone tell me how to suppress this "incompatible pointer type" warning?

Answer (score 5):

I have checked the documentation of GCC (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/). The option "-Wno-incompatible-pointer-types" is not yet available in the latest GCC 4.x version, but it is available as of the first GCC 5.x versions.

Since you are using GCC version 4.2.1 you can't use option "-Wno-incompatible-pointer-types" yet. Please migrate to GCC 5.x or later.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to suppress all incompatible pointer type warnings for the whole project because of some third-party code you don't have control over. Instead, consider suppressing all warnings caused by processing this third-party code, while retaining all warnings for the code of your own.

You can do this by specifying third-party headers as "system headers". GCC has an option for this. Instead of passing third-party headers using the `-I` argument, use `-isystem` instead. System headers are treated specially by GCC and warnings are not generated for them (excluding the ones caused by `#pragma warning`).

Comment: Thanks Nikita! Is there any ignore flag such as  "-Wno- " for this particular warning?

Comment: Probably not. Try compiling with `-fdiagnostics-show-option` argument.  For warnings that can be suppressed, there will be warning names in the output. If you don't see any names or see something like `[enabled by default]`, you're out of luck.

Comment: I tried -fdiagnostics-show-option. It works for other type of warnings (unsused, sign-compare etc). But it is not providing any information for the following two warning types:  incompatible pointer type, left shift count >= width of type

Comment: There are probably other types of warnings that cannot be suppressed using `-W` flags and pragmas. But you can still use the `-isystem` trick.